# JOLT: Merge a field into nested object

Tags: json, jolt

I'm new to JOLT. I have this json object

```json
{
  "query_time": "2021-20-25 12:10:12.000",
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "places": {
        "city": "Edmonton",
        "address": "example address 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "places": {
        "city": "Winnipeg",
        "address": "example address 2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to transform it into this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Edmonton",
    "address": "example address 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Winnipeg",
    "address": "example address 2"
    
  }
]
```

Please help me define a JOLT spec to do this transformation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the elements nested in the `places` key by using `"*"` wildcard while looking up the values of `id` elements by going one level up through use of `@(1,id)` within a **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "locations": {
        "*": {
          "places": {
            "@1,id": "[&2].id",
            "*": "[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: There was an error in my input, and your solution works perfectly after I correct the input. Thanks

Comment: exactly, forgot to tell that the JSON needed to be fixed @nautilusvn , you're welcome.